# firebase-admin WebSocket Error

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I have problems with firebase-admin. Apparently I cant establish a WebSocket connection with firebase.

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("./realtimedemo-c6eae-firebase-adminsdk.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "https://realtimedemo-c6eae.firebaseapp.com"
});


admin.database.enableLogging(true)

var defaultDatabase = admin.database();
var ref = defaultDatabase.ref();
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    console.log(snapshot.val());

}, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

[image: screenshot from console]

thx, in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer.

The databaseURL was incorrect. The ending has to be "....firebaseio.com" instead of "firebaseapp.com".